# Use variable thats filled in later javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the header

I have a link

Header

```
document.write('<a href="example.com/index.html?week='  + WeekW + '">');
```

The body changes based on the content so the WeekW changes with it.

Body

```
var WeekW = 53;
```

Ofcourse it gives me now it does not exist...what can be done ?

Comment: Define the value before you try to use it?  Or write to the header after the value is defined?

Comment: @David when i do var WeekW before i use it..its undefined

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  You can't use something before it exists.  What you need to do is define the value (not just declare the variable, but *define the value*) and *then* use it, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices:

- Set your variable before the `document.write`.  This seems unlikely, since from what you say, you don't know the value of `WeekW` when you're writing your line.
- Write a placeholder, and once you calculate your `WeekW`, you can fill in the placeholder.  The easiest way to do this is simply write an anchor with a unique id:

  `document.write('<a id="myUniqueIdRightHere" >');`

Later on, when you have set `WeekW`, go back and change your anchor:

```
document.getElementById('myUniqueIdRightHere').href = "example.com/index.html?week=" + WeekW;
```

Another alternative is to insert the full anchor with complete href into the document in the appropriate position after `WeekW` is set.  You'd need to know enough about the surrounding parts of the document, but should be able to find something and attach the anchor at that point using things like the `get*` functions and `appendChild`.